# How To Find The Nearest Palindrome Number?

Tags: java, algorithm, palindrome

Well i tried to write a program in java to find the palindrome , someone asked me to add a twist in that and the twist goes like this we have to find whether the number is palindrome or not if not then we have to find the nearest palindrome number. For example if the number entered is 37 then there are two numbers which can be palindrome near it one is 33 and the other is 44, but the nearer is 33 so here 33 is the answer. I tried lot to write it but without success :(

```
import java.io.*;  
public class NearestPalindrome {  
static int i,j,n,m,f,r=0,g,p1,p2,c1=0,c2=0,a;  
static boolean k;  
public static void main (String []agrs)throws IOException  
{
   BufferedReader A = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));  
   System.out.println("This Program Is Created For Checking Whether The Number Entered Is Palindrome, If Not Find The Nearest Palindrome..");  
   System.out.println("Please Enter Number:-");  
   n=Integer.parseInt(A.readLine());
   f=n;  
   NearestPalindrome.Palindrome(f);  
   if(r==f)
   {System.out.println("This Is A Palindrome Number:-"+r);}
   else
   {
       for(i=n;((c1==1)&&(c2==1));i--)
       {
           NearestPalindrome.Palindrome(i);  
           NearestPalindrome.Palindrome(j);  
           if(k=true)  
           { if(r==i)  
           {   p1=i;  
           c1++;  
           }  
           if(r==j)  
               {p2=j;  
               c2++;  
               }  
               }  
           }  
       if((n-p1)>(p2-n))    
       {
        System.out.println("The Nearest Palindrome Is:-"+p2);  
       }  
       else  
        System.out.println("The Nearest Palindrome Is:-"+p1);  

       }  

   }  
public static boolean Palindrome (int x)
{


    for(i=0;x>0;i++)
       {
           m=x%10;
           r=r*10+m;
           x=x/10;   
       }  
    if(n==r)
    {k=true;}
    else
        k=false;
return k;
}
```

}

Comment: Something went wrong up there in that code else part it not executing and the answer is always 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you going in the right direction

```
public class MyClass {

    public int findNearestPalindrome(int numberEntered) {
        int lowerPalidrome = getLowerPalindrome(numberEntered);
        int higherPalindrome = getHigherPalindrome(numberEntered);
        if (Math.abs(numberEntered - lowerPalindrome) < Math.abs(numberEntered - higherPalindrome) {
            return lowerPalindrome;
        } else {
            return higherPalindrom;
        }
    }

    public int getLowerPalindrome(int baseNumber) {
        for (int i = baseNumber; i > 0; i--) {
            //do logic to find palindrome and return it
        }
    }

    public int getHigherPalindrome(int baseNumber) {
        for (int i = baseNumber; i < LARGE_NUMBER; i++) {
            //do logic to find palindrome and return it
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind there are definitely multiple ways you could do this. You could use a `while` loop for example, instead of the `for` loop. I hope this helps!

Edit: If you really want to compress code I suggest you create a method that finds the palindrome and use it in both methods.

Comment: thanks i really appreciate it that code looks nice and small!

Comment: @Brandon laidig what is LARGE_NUMBER ??

Answer (score 3):

It can be done more efficiently.

Suppose, we have `N` digits. Let's find prefix of length `N / 2`. After that, you can construct 3 possible answers using 2 nearest prefixes, and find the nearest palindrome (you should think about corner cases here).

Example:

Number `123456789` has `1234` prefix of length `9/2 = 4`. Nearest prefixes: `1233`, `1235`.

Then we just construct 3 candidates: `123353321`, `123454321` and `123555321`

```
abs(123456789 - 123353321) = 103468
abs(123456789 - 123454321) = 2468
abs(123456789 - 123555321) = 98532
```

So the nearest palindrom will be `123454321`.

UPD: You have to try all possible middle digits also in this case.

Comment: The middle digit can be anything, so you'd probably want 123393321 and 123505321, but this is definitely the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

Code using basic Java with arrays and StringBuilder

```
    package newPackage;

public class AmazonQn6FindNearestPalindromeNumber {
    static int before;
    static int after;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println();

        int num=1221;
        AmazonQn6FindNearestPalindromeNumber n1=new AmazonQn6FindNearestPalindromeNumber();

        before = num-1;
        after = num+1;


        int[] checkPalindrome= new int[2];

        do {
            checkPalindrome = n1.checkPalindrome(before, after);        
            if((checkPalindrome[0] >0)||(checkPalindrome[1] >0)) {
            System.out.println("Numbers are");
            for(int n:checkPalindrome) {
                System.out.println(n);
            }


            if(checkPalindrome[0]!=0)
                System.out.println("Nearest Palindrome is "+checkPalindrome[0]);

            if(checkPalindrome[1]!=0)
                System.out.println("Nearest Palindrome is "+checkPalindrome[1]);

            break;
            }
        //  checkPalindrome = n1.checkPalindrome(before, after);

        }while((checkPalindrome[0] ==0)||(checkPalindrome[1] ==0));

    }

    public int[] checkPalindrome(Integer n, Integer m) {
        before = before-1;
        after = after+1;
        int[] array = new int[2];

        String stringn = n.toString();
        StringBuilder string1 = new StringBuilder(stringn);
        System.out.println(string1);
        StringBuilder string2 = string1.reverse();
        System.out.println(string2);
        if(stringn.equals(string2.toString()))
        {   
            array[0]=n;
            System.out.println("Element in n" +array[0]);

        }

        String stringm = m.toString();
        StringBuilder string3 = new StringBuilder(stringm);
        System.out.println(string3);
        StringBuilder string4 = string3.reverse();
        System.out.println(string4);

        if(stringm.equals(string4.toString()))
        {
            array[1]=m;
            System.out.println("Element in m" +array[1]);

        }

        return array;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest Code to find Nearest palindrome.
For example if the input is 37. Nearest palindrome to 37 is 33 and 44. But the difference is 4 and 7 respectively. Hence output is 33. If difference is equal in both case it will print both the numbers.

```
package demo;

import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.text.html.FormSubmitEvent;

public class Increment {


    public static boolean Plaindrome(int n) {
          int r,sum=0,temp;

          temp=n;    
          while(n>0){    
           r=n%10;  
           sum=(sum*10)+r;    
           n=n/10;    
          }    
          if(temp==sum)    
              return true;
          else    
           return false; 

        }  
    public static int  greaterpalindrome(int k) {
        while(!Plaindrome(k)) {

             k++;

         }
        return k;
    }
    public static int  smallerpalindrome(int s) {
        while(!Plaindrome(s)) {

            s--;

         }
        return s;}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         int value = scan.nextInt();

         int greater = greaterpalindrome(value+1);

         int smaller = smallerpalindrome(value-1);

         if (Math.abs(value-greater)==(value-smaller)) {
                System.out.println(greater+" "+smaller);
            }
            else if (Math.abs(value-greater)>(value-smaller)) {
                System.out.println(smaller);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(greater);
            }

        } }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.lang.*;
    import java.io.*;
    class GFG
     {  public static int findcount(int n)
     {
         int count=0;
         while(n!=0)
         {
             n=n/10;
             count++;
         }
         return count;
     }
public static int findpalindrome(int arr)
 {
     int rem=0,count=0;
    while(arr>0)
    {
        rem=arr%10;
        count=(count*10)+rem;
        arr=arr/10;
    }
     return count;
 }
public static void main (String[] args) 
 {
 //code
 Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
 int test=sc.nextInt();

 while(test-->0)
 { 
    int n=sc.nextInt();
     int res=0,flag=0,flag11=0,j=n+1,i=n-1;
     int aa=0,bb=0;
     if(findcount(n)==1 || (n==findpalindrome(n)) )
        System.out.println(n);
     else
     { 

         for(i=n-1;i>0;i--)
         {

          if(i==findpalindrome(i))
          {    
              aa=i;
              break;
          }  

         }
         while(flag!=1)
         { 
          if(j==findpalindrome(j))
          {    
              bb=j;
              flag=1;
              break;
          }
         j++;  
         } 
       int dif1=Math.abs(n-aa);
       int dif2=Math.abs(n-bb);
       if((dif1==dif2) || (dif1<dif2))
        System.out.println(aa);
       else
       System.out.println(bb);
     }

 }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code snippet:

```java
public class Sample{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter val: ");
        
        int entry = scan.nextInt();
        int entryN = entry;
        int entryP = entry;

        while(true) {
            if (isPolindrom(entry)) {
                System.out.println(entry);
                break;
            } else if (isPolindrom(--entryN)) {
                System.out.println(entryN);
                break;
            } else if (isPolindrom(++entryP)){
                System.out.println(entryP);
                break;
            }
        }   
        
        System.out.println("Best hakiki mürşit is a science :)");
        
    }

    private static boolean isPolindrom(int a) {
        int val1 = a;
        int last = 0;
        int size = String.valueOf(val1).length();
        
        for(int i = size; i > 0 ; i-- ) {
            
            last += (val1 % 10) * (int) Math.pow(10, (i-1));
            val1 = (val1 - (val1 % 10)) /10;
        }
        if (a == last) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }       
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
package com.amit.practice;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test= new Test();
        int polyNum=test.polydrum(813123);
        System.out.println(polyNum);
    }

    public int polydrum(int number){
        int finalNum=0;
        System.out.println("The given number is :"+number+" ");
        do {
            String revString = "";
            String numString=""+number;
            int numLength=numString.length();

            for(int i=numLength-1;i>=0;i--){
                revString += numString.charAt(i);
                if(numString.equals(revString)){
                    System.out.println("The next polydrum number is :"+numString);
                    finalNum=Integer.parseInt(revString);
                    return finalNum;
                }
            }
            number=number+1;
        } while(finalNum!=number);

        return finalNum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This code is to find the NEAREST Palindrome number by using nearestPalindrome(int number) method and other method to find NEXT Palindrome number using nextPalindrome(int number).

```
package com.amit.palindrome;

public class Palindrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Palindrome test= new Palindrome();
        int number=135625978;
        System.out.println("Given Number is :"+number);

        int nearestPolyNum=test.nearestPalindrome(number);
        int nextPolyNum=test.nextPalindrome(number);
        System.out.println("Nearest Palindrome Number is :"+nearestPolyNum);
        System.out.println("Next Palindrome Number is :"+nextPolyNum);
    }

    public int nextPalindrome(int number){
        int nextPoly=0;
        if(number>9){
            do {
                String revString = "";
                String numString=""+number;
                int numLength=numString.length();

                for(int i=numLength-1;i>=0;i--){
                    revString += numString.charAt(i);
                    if(numString.equals(revString)){
                        nextPoly=Integer.parseInt(revString);
                        return nextPoly;
                    }
                }
                number=number+1;
            } while(nextPoly!=number);
            return nextPoly;
        }
       return number;
    }



    public int nearestPalindrome(int number){

        if(number>9){
                String revString = "";
                String numString=""+number;
                int nearestPoly=0;
                int numLength=numString.length();           

                    String anotherHalfNumber=null;
                    int halfNum = numLength/2;
                    String firstHalfNumber=numString.substring(0, halfNum);
                    if(numLength%2==0){
                        anotherHalfNumber=numString.substring(halfNum);
                    }else{
                        anotherHalfNumber=numString.substring(halfNum+1);
                    }               
                    for(int i=firstHalfNumber.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
                        revString += firstHalfNumber.charAt(i);                

                    }
                    int intAnotherHalfNumber=Integer.parseInt(anotherHalfNumber);
                    int reverseFirstHalfNumber=Integer.parseInt(revString);
                    int adjustedNumber = intAnotherHalfNumber-reverseFirstHalfNumber;
                    nearestPoly = number-adjustedNumber;
                    return nearestPoly;
        }
         return number;
    }
}
```

Comment: Care to explain why this is the answer to the question?

Comment: The code is to find the NEAREST Palindrome number by using nearestPalindrome(int number) method and other method to find NEXT Palindrome number using nextPalindrome(int number).

Comment: Doesn't work for 1999 -> 2002 . 1999 input returns 1991, but nearest is 2002.